# Sphinx not working on 2.2.10

Tags: php, sphinx

I update Sphinx version from 2.1.8 to 2.2.10 , but it seems doesn't much the same result as it was , and now sphinx act weird . 
here is my conf :

```
source tdp_products_src
{
        type                    = mysql

        sql_host                = 127.0.0.1
        sql_user                = root
        sql_pass                = 
        sql_db                  = mydb
        sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

        sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8

        sql_query               = \
                SELECT p.product_id , p.name, b.name as brand_name, p.url, p.description, p.properties from product p \
                LEFT join brand b on p.brand_fk = b.brand_id \
                WHERE  p.deleted != 1 AND p.confirmed = 1

        sql_attr_uint           = url

        sql_query_info          = SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id=$id
}

indexer
{
        mem_limit               = 32M
}

index tdp_products
{
        source                  = tdp_products_src
        path                    = /var/www/project/Sphinx/data/tdp_products
        docinfo                 = extern
        charset_type            = utf-8
        min_infix_len = 3

}

searchd
{
        listen                  = 9312
        listen                  = 9306:mysql41
        log                     = /var/www/project/Sphinx/log/searchd.log
        query_log               = /var/www/project/Sphinx/log/query.log
        read_timeout            = 5
        max_children            = 30
        pid_file                = /var/www/project/Sphinx/log/searchd.pid
        max_matches             = 1000
        seamless_rotate         = 1
        preopen_indexes         = 1
        unlink_old              = 1
        workers                 = threads # for RT to work
        binlog_path             = /var/www/project/Sphinx/data
}
```

am using a PHP SphinxClient **gigablah/sphinxphp** , here's what i tried :

```
$s = new SphinxClient;
$s->setServer($config['sphinx']['host'],$config['sphinx']['port']);
$s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
$foundProducts = $s->Query($data->phrase, 'tdp_products');
```

My database has more than 800 products, and i use sphinx for autocomplete search , it was working before i update sphinx.

Comment: Please define 'weird'...  - what **exactly** is going wrong, will help point to what is causing it.

Comment: Sphinx match results has nothing to do with the given phrase, for example : when i type 'nut' it should match all product's name has this phrase like "New Nutella ..." , but it render nothing, but when i write the whole word "nutella", it works

Comment: Something Sphinx match products has nothing to do with the given phrase